# selecting data from array

Tags: arrays, matlab, selection, sampling

I want to select data in an array that has a sampling frequency of 0.02 i.e. 0, 0.02, 0.04, etc.
I want to extract data from this so that my data has a sampling frequency of 0.3 i.e. 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, etc. 
What's the best way to do this considering I may have to choose data between 0.29 or 0.31 from the array?

Amit

Answer (score 0):

You could read up on `resample` and give this a try assuming that you are downsampling 15-fold:

```
y = resample(x, 1, 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like an interpolation problem than resampling. Resampling must be done by a rational factor. In your question you are looking to estimate data that was not acquired. Try [interp1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html)

```
maxSample=(length(data)-1)*0.02;
y=interp1(0:0.02:maxSample,data,0:0.03:maxSample);
```